# AutoFac creating type regardless of existence

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I want to use AutoFac to inject references into an object's constructor.  However, the actual object itself is not registered.  I am doing this for an ASP.NET MVC controller factory, where the controller won't be registered, but the constructor params will be.  I managed to do this in unity, but I am having trouble with AutoFac.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Autofac can't resolve a type that hasn't been registered, even when this type is concrete with a single public constructor.

In your situation this problem however can be solved easily, because there is an [Mvc3Ingegration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Mvc3Integration) package for Autofac that contains a `RegisterControllers` extension method for the builder. You can use it as follows:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
```

Comment: As described below - you *can* make Autofac do this, but it isn't recommended.

Answer (score 9):

To have Autofac resolve any unregistered type the way Unity does:

```
builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());
```

An early version of this solution is described [here](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/resolve-anything/).

However, I +1ed Steven's answer and would encourage you to use it rather than the above. With Autofac you're better off using the pre-built MVC integration. It is a piece of cake to set up on MVC3 - see [these step-by-step instructions](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/autofac-2-4-is-here-%E2%80%93-come-and-%E2%80%9Cnuget%E2%80%9D-it/).

Even if you build your own controller factory, life will be more predictable if you don't rely on the 'resolve anything' behaviour :)